# Paypal NVP API Recurring Profile Upgrade Profile Charge surplus amount at a time and Next Billing Cycle

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing, paypal-nvp

I tried using simple CreateRecurringProfile and UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile of Paypal NVP apis.

I have confusion If i can achieve my goal or not Please suggest me the solutions

Case 1:

Silver Package = $20
Gold Package = $100

My Custome created Recurring Payment with Billing Cycle of $20 Per month for 6 months on Jan 1st For silver Subscription Plan.

Later on Customer come back on Feb 2nd and updates his subscription package from silver to gold subscription at that time i want to update to subscription plan as All next billing cycle will charge to $100 from $20 but when he upgrades he/she must be charges $80 (i.e sur plus amount) because remaining $20 is paid on Feb 1st's Bill.

Thanks in Advance

Please suggest me some solutions.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case, You can cancel Recurring payment Profile, And create new Profile for $100 as Recurring amount And $80 as Initial Amount ( INITAMT as given in documentation of CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile)